# Stay Awake Option Not Available M9

Tags: settings, htc

I am using the HTC M9, and when I go into "Developer Options" the "Stay Awake" option is grayed out. Why? How can I fix? What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this but I can provide alternative solution for stay awake...

[Stay Awake - Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji)

Try this... And if not working you may find other similar apps on store... :-)